# Jhipster 5 microservice not starting properly

Tags: jhipster

I'm just starting using jHipster 5 but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I generate a microservice project without any errors.
Then I start it with the command ./mvnw without any errors in logs

But when I try to connect to localhost:8081 I have either a blank page or a 404 error. I generated an entity and populated my database and again, a `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8081/api/cars'` command doesn't return anything

A few months ago, I developped a microservce in jHipster 4.14.0 without having this kind of problem.

Comment: Hey, were you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing this.

Comment: Actually, everything works fine. It's just that now, there is a context path added by default in application.yml (server:  servlet:  context-path: ${spring.application.name})

Answer (score 0):

I found some kind of workaround. Instead of doing a `jhipster` command to build a new projet, I used the command `jhipster server`. 
In my case, it was enough since I was simply trying to build a simple Rest API without a microservice architecture.